# How to get value of input from next()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need to retrieve data from an input but the id is dynamic. I only know the previous name of the field, in my snippet is **Login** and **Password**.
Here is what I tried :

```js
console.log($( "td:contains('Login')").next('input').val());
console.log($( "td:contains('Login')").next('td > input').val());
console.log($( "td:contains('Login')").next('tr > td > input').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Login</td>
    <td class="fieldarea" colspan="3">
        <input type="text" name="customfield[52]" id="customfield52" value="Somelogin" size="30" class="form-control">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Password</td>
    <td class="fieldarea" colspan="3">
        <input type="text" name="customfield[53]" id="customfield53" value="Somepass" size="30" class="form-control">
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I get the values of the both input ?

**EDIT**

I have a new question related to this topic.

I now have a second input field (Password and Login). How can I get the second input value. In my situation it's the first input I get.

```js
var password_user = $( "tr:nth-child(2) > td:contains('Password')").next('td').find('input').val();
console.log(password_user);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="form" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Order #</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%">1 - <a href="#">View Order</a></td>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Registration Date</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%"><input type="text" name="regdate" value="22/01/2011" size="12" class="form-control date-picker hasDatepicker" id="dp1540302344931"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Product/Service</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%">
            <input type="hidden" name="oldpackageid" value="70">
            <select name="packageid" class="form-control select-inline-long">
               <optgroup label="lbl">
                  <option value="86">TEST1</option>
                  <option value="87">TEST2</option>
               </optgroup>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">First Payment Amount</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%"><input type="text" name="firstpaymentamount" value="10" size="10" class="form-control input-100"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Server</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%">
            <select name="server" class="form-control select-inline">
               <option value="232">TEST2</option>
               <option value="234">TEST1</option>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Recurring Amount</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%"><input type="text" name="amount" value="10" size="10" class="form-control input-100 input-inline"> <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="autorecalcrecurringprice" value="1"> Auto Recalculate on Save</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Domain</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%">
            <div class="input-group input-300">
               <input type="text" name="domain" value="test" class="form-control">
               <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-left:-3px;">
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                     <li><a href="http://test.com" target="_blank">www</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">whois</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" target="_blank">intoDNS</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Next Due Date</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%"><input type="hidden" name="oldnextduedate" value="22/07/2019"><input type="text" name="nextduedate" value="22/07/2019" size="12" class="form-control date-picker hasDatepicker" id="17852"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Dedicated IP</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%"><input type="text" name="dedicatedip" value="789456" size="25" class="form-control input-200"></td>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Termination Date</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%"><input type="text" name="termination_date" value="" size="12" class="form-control date-picker hasDatepicker" id="12545412"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Username</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%"><input type="text" name="username" value="testUser" size="20" class="form-control input-200 input-inline"> </td>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Billing Cycle</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%">
            <select name="billingcycle" class="form-control select-inline">
               <option value="Free Account">Free</option>
               <option value="One Time">One Time</option>
               <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
               <option value="Quarterly" selected="">Quarterly</option>
               <option value="Semi-Annually">Semi-Annually</option>
               <option value="Annually">Annually</option>
               <option value="Biennially">Biennially</option>
               <option value="Triennially">Triennially</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Password</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%"><input type="text" name="password" value="Pass" size="20" class="form-control input-200"></td>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Payment Method</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%">
            <select name="paymentmethod" class="form-control select-inline">
               <option value="paypal" selected="">PayPal</option>
            </select>
            <a href="#">View Invoices</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Status</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%">
            <select name="domainstatus" class="form-control select-inline" id="prodstatus">
               <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
               <option value="Active" selected="">Active</option>
               <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
               <option value="Suspended">Suspended</option>
               <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
               <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
               <option value="Fraud">Fraud</option>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Promotion Code</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" width="30%">
            <select name="promoid" class="form-control select-inline">
               <option value="0">None</option>
               <option value="463">CODETEST - 40.00% One Time</option>
            </select>
            <br>(Change will not affect price)
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Module Commands</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" colspan="3">
            <div id="modcmdbtns">
                <button style="margin-left:4px;" id="diagnostic_btn_Custom" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#diagnosticModal">Diagnostic</button>
               <div class="modal fade" id="diagnosticModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                     <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                           <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Diagnostic</h5>
                           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                           <div style="margin-left:5px;" class="row">Transmission: <span style="display: none;" id="loader_transmission"><img style="height:5px; width:auto" src="images/loader.gif"></span><span id="transmission_res" style="color: rgb(46, 204, 64);">✔</span></div>
                           <div style="margin-left:5px;" class="row">FTP: <span style="display: none;" id="loader_ftp"><img style="height:5px; width:auto" src="images/loader.gif"></span><span id="ftp_res" style="color: rgb(255, 65, 54);"></span></div>
                           <div style="margin-left:5px;" class="row">Nextcloud: <span style="display: none;" id="nextcloud_loader"><img style="height:5px; width:auto" src="images/loader.gif"></span><span id="nextcloud_res" style="color: rgb(255, 65, 54);"></span></div>
                           <div style="margin-left:5px;" class="row">Coffre-fort: <span style="display: none;" id="loader_coffre"><img style="height:5px; width:auto" src="images/loader.gif"></span><span id="coffre_res" style="color: rgb(255, 65, 54);"></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               
            </div>
            <div id="modcmdworking" style="display:none;text-align:center;"><img src="images/loader.gif"> &nbsp; Working...</div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Addons</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" colspan="3">
            <div class="tablebg">
               <table id="sortabletbl1" class="datatable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Reg Date</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Pricing</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Next Due Date</th>
                        <th width="20"></th>
                        <th width="20"></th>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="7">No Records Found</td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>

         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Login</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" colspan="3"><input type="text" value="GETTHISVALUE" size="30" class="form-control"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Password</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" colspan="3"><input type="text" value="GETTHISVALUE" size="30" class="form-control"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Subscription ID</td>
         <td class="fieldarea" colspan="3">
            <div class="input-group input-500" id="subscription">
               <input type="text" name="subscriptionid" value="I-123" size="25" class="form-control">
               <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  id="btnCancel_Subscription" style="margin-left:-3px;">
               Cancel Subscription
               </button>
               </span>
            </div>
            <div id="subscriptionworking" style="display:none;text-align:center;"><img src="images/loader.gif">&nbsp; Working...</div>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you running this logic under and element's event handler? It may be possible to traverse the DOM to find the related element from that.

Comment: Nop it's not under event handler

Comment: Assign common class to all input element for which you wan't to get value, they with that class you can get the value using single line.

Comment: But I don't have dom access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two problem.

1- `<tr>` should wrapped into `<table>` to be valid html.

2- The `input` isn't next element after `td`. You should get next `td` first and then select `input` in it.

```js
console.log($("td:contains('Login')").next('td').find('input').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Login</td>
    <td class="fieldarea" colspan="3">
      <input type="text" name="customfield[52]" id="customfield52" value="Somelogin" size="30" class="form-control">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Password</td>
    <td class="fieldarea" colspan="3">
      <input type="text" name="customfield[53]" id="customfield53" value="Somepass" size="30" class="form-control">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @executable That's not a good thing to change question after posting multiple answer. You should post new question instead. However check http://jsfiddle.net/edvy1Lg2/

Comment: I don't want to post multiple question which are pretty similar

Answer (score 1):

First don't use the text as discriminator. Set an ID instead on the Element, it is much more effective. If you can then just set classes to both inputs and select them by class. Also much cleaner and more effective.

If you are screen scraping and can't change the html code then I would suggest Selecting all the relevant ````` and looping over them in code. There you have much better tools to your disposal. eg.

```
$("tr")
.toArray()
.filter((el) => /Login|Password/.exec($(el).text()) !== null)
.map((el) => el.querySelector("input"));
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign common class name to all that input element for which you want to get the value.

Check below code.

```js
$(".data").each(function(k,v){console.log($(v).val())})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
 <tr>
    <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Login</td>
    <td class="fieldarea" colspan="3">
        <input type="text" name="customfield[52]" id="customfield52" value="Somelogin" size="30" class="form-control data">
    </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="fieldlabel" width="20%">Password</td>
  <td class="fieldarea" colspan="3">
   <input type="text" name="customfield[53]" id="customfield53" value="Somepass" size="30" class="form-control data">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't have access to the dom

Comment: @executable then you can try something like **$(".fieldarea input").each(function(k,v){console.log($(v).val())})** this code.